# WooCommerce Event Tracking, PHP + JS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to track woo commerce events using a custom plugin.

I added the provided tracking code to the header using the wp_head hook, and I need to track pageviews, searches, product views...etc.

I wrote something like this,

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array(
             &$this,
            'viewed_product'
        ) , 15);
```

And the function :

```
   public function viewed_product()
    {
        $product_id = get_the_ID();
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
?>
    <script>
        xyz.push({
            "track"            : "productview",
            "product_id"       : <?php echo $product_id ?>,
            "product_name"     : <?php echo $product->get_name() ?>,
            "product_price"    : <?php echo $product->get_price() ?>,,
        });
    </script>
<?php
```

I can see that the tracking code is loaded in the header. But when I viewed the product it gives the error,

> _xyz is not defined

Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: whatever that `_xyz` object is, it's either not loading on the product page or loading after your code, you need to validate if it exists on that page or not. If it does then it's before your code or after your code check that then fix your issues based on debugging results.